# issues with UDP server and client in C

Tags: c++, c, network-programming, udp

I am trying to send/receive some data across 2 computers (mac, ubuntu) using a UDP connection and they are connected with an ethernet cable. When I run the server to receive some data from  a client, I get the data but if I send it back, the client does not receive it. On further investigation, I found out that the clientAddress that I store upon recvfrom() does not have information relating to the ipaddress and port of the client (it is all zeroes). Any clues on what might be going wrong ?

```
n = recvfrom(sockfd, msg, 1000, 0, (sockaddr *)&clientAddress, &len);
sendto(sockfd, msg, n, 0, (sockaddr *)&clientAddress, sizeof(clientAddress));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you populate `len` before calling `recvfrom`, it's a value-result argument.

```
len = sizeof(clientAddress);
n = recvfrom(sockfd, msg, 1000, 0, (sockaddr *)&clientAddress, &len);
```